# How can I play HD video in android 4.2 native player using some codec

Tags: android, android-videoview, codec

I am creating an application where I have to play HD video by using native player(videoview). Is there any **codec** which can support my native **player for playing high resolution video**.

right now I am getting an error

> "**Can't play the video**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VideoView supports HD videos, it's more likely that the format of the video you use is not supported by default on Android. You can take a look at the [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) to have an idea.

It also seems that some dev are using the [Vitamino Library](http://www.vitamio.org/en/) to play some more exotic formats

Hope this help!

Comment: I am running .mp4 video which is working fine, but when i try to run the .mp4 video of high resolution then it gives that message"Can't play the video".

Comment: Thanks, It works fine.But I am not able to play multiple video simultaneously by using vitamino library

Comment: I've never used Vitamino so I can't help you. But if my answer helped you you can upvote it please ;)

Comment: Is there any other player which can run HD video and whose code is available easily.